# PHP + Google API Geocode

Tags: php, google-maps, geolocalização

Segue o código do método:

```
function GetGeoCode($address) {
    $geo= array();

    $geocode = file_get_html('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . $address . '&sensor=false');
    $output = json_decode($geocode);
    echo 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . $address . '&sensor=false';
    $lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $long = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

    $geo['lat']=$lat;
    $geo['long']=$long;

    return $geo;
}
```

O Objetivo desse método é retornar a latitude e longitude de acordo com um determinado endereço inserido como parâmetro. Porem, após realizar o teste com alguns endereços da o erro de não retornar os dados. Realizei o teste de copiar a url criada e colar no navegador, a qual funcionou corretamente.

Alguém sabe me dizer porque acontece isso ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realizei alguns testes, primeiramente, ao invés de `file_get_html` utilizei no código abaixo `file_get_contents`, porém o que percebi no teste pelo menos utilizando este método, é que precisa enviar o parâmetro com os **espaços** substituídos por **+**, percebi também que utilizando acentuações retorna *NULL*, desta forma foi resolvido com o código abaixo com explicação em próprio comentário.

```
$geo= array();
$a = "Rua Paulo Guimarães, São Paulo - SP"; // Pega parâmetro
$addr = str_replace(" ", "+", $a); // Substitui os espaços por + "Rua+Paulo+Guimarães,+São+Paulo+-+SP" conforme padrão 'maps.google.com'
$address = utf8_encode($addr); // Codifica para UTF-8 para não dar 'pau' no envio do parâmetro

// Daqui em diante é o seu código original
$geocode = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . $address . '&sensor=false');
$output = json_decode($geocode);
$lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$long = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

$geo['lat']=$lat;
$geo['long']=$long;

echo "<pre> Latitude: ";
print_r($geo['lat']);
echo "<br /> Longitude: ";
print_r($geo['long']);
echo "<br /><br /> Resultado completo JSON: <br /><br />";
print_r($output);
```

> Não fiz testes no seu código para entender o que estava ocorrendo, mas pelo que pude perceber o problema deveria estar no envio (formato) do parâmetro.

De qualquer modo, sugiro que dedique um tempinho a esta leitura para que não precisemos fazer este tipo de 'gambiarra' sendo que existe uma API toda documentada com inúmeras possibilidades, assim também não ficará limitado caso queira incrementar sua funcionalidade.

> Leitura sugerida: [The Google Mas Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)

Comment: Valeu mesmo. Eu realizei algumas alterações aqui de acordo com o que me mandou e funcionou. Porem vou seguir mesmo a sujestão de leitura da documentação pois ainda ocorrem algumas exceções a qual continua a não retornar. Meu código esta bem feio e bem 'gambiarra' mesmo.